# index match instead using vlookup

Tags: excel, match, vlookup, indexof

I have two csv files.
First csv

```
Id Name Price Description 
1    X    2     lalala
2    Y    4     nanana
3    Z    6     papapa
```

and another:

```
Id   Description 
2     here
6     here 
1     here
```

I want to replace description from first csv file if ids are the same, if they are not then save the previous value from description from second csv. I want to this via index match function, what is the best way to do it?

Comment: Index will use the target range ie column, match uses the lookup range - have a look at the vlookup its index column and result column.

Comment: There are examples of the use of index and match on this site - worth looking for...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For such queries the best way is to try them yourself, even if you fail at first but you would learn even  if you fail or succeed, the best way would have been that you had searched the internet for index match and try to implement that on your data.

but as you are here, I shall try to make it clear how it is done

**Match function** finds a value in a range and when it finds it; it will return its position in that range (which is the relative row number if we have provided a column range)

**Index function** can be used on that returned position. We can give index a range and provide a position to it. It return a value at this particular location from the provided range.
The trick is; that in this case we shall provide a different column and it will return data from that column

[image]

I am going to explain one row (#8), all other rows are same

- Match Result B8: it is using match() to search the id in A8 in the
  range A2 to A4, and when it finds that range it is returning its
  position in that range which is 2
- Index result C8: it is using index function() to retrieve the value
  at position 2 (returned by match in previous line) from the range D2
  to D4, as it is nanana it will return that.

D8 to D10 is same formula but combined

The formulas in the cells are as below

```
B8: =MATCH(A8,$A$2:$A$4)
C8: =INDEX($D$2:$D$4,B8)
D8: =INDEX($D$2:$D$4,MATCH(A8,$A$2:$A$4))
```

Comment: It may be worth making clear that the range length must be the same for both index and match...